# problems while trying to optimize my SQL(inner join and group)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, inner-join

Im having a problem in joining and grouping two table. Im using **ms sql server 2005 express** .

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `date_request` to your `JOIN` criteria:

```
SELECT otd.userid,otd.task,otd.date_request,ot.approved_by 
FROM otd
JOIN ot 
  ON otd.userid = ot.requested_by
  AND otd.date_request = ot.date_request
WHERE otd.userid ='xxx' 
  AND CONVERT(varchar,otd.date_request,101) BETWEEN '09/10/2013' AND '09/11/2013'
  AND ot.status ='A'
ORDER BY otd.date_request,ot.date_request ASC
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/220b0/7/0)

Note: Date is changed in Fiddle, but the extra `JOIN` criteria is the important part. Also, not sure what you're converting your date field for, but if it's a `DATE` you can just alter the format of your date strings and not cast (as it is in fiddle).

Comment: thank you for your response and idea. i just add **AND otd.date_request = ot.date_request** and it gives me the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your schema, there's no way to determine which task in `otd` the record in `ot` is referring to.  Perhaps you meant to include a task column in `ot`?  For example, take a look at your first record in `otd`.  Task 1 by user xxx requested on `9/10/2013`.  Now look at all the records in `ot`.  You're joining `ot` on `otd.userid = ot.requested_by`, and there are two records in `ot` requested by xxx.  So that join matches those two records for task 1 by xxx, and the same two records for task 2 by xxx, and again for tasks 5 and 6.